# Bootstrap Table of Contents plugin : calling the "$scope" object to include more headings

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use this Table of Contents plugin : https://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc/

I can't find out of how to properly call the $scope object, which would allow h1 to h6 headings to be integrated in the TOC. So far, only h1 to h3 are.

Here's the bit of code :

```
!function(){"use strict";window.Toc={helpers:{findOrFilter:function(e,t){var r=e.find(t);return e.filter(t).add(r).filter(":not([data-toc-skip])")},generateUniqueIdBase:function(e){var t=$(e).text(),r=t.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g,"-");return r||e.tagName.toLowerCase()},generateUniqueId:function(e){for(var t=this.generateUniqueIdBase(e),r=0;;r++){var n=t;if(r>0&&(n+="-"+r),!document.getElementById(n))return n}},generateAnchor:function(e){if(e.id)return e.id;var t=this.generateUniqueId(e);return e.id=t,t},createNavList:function(){return $('<ul class="nav"></ul>')},createChildNavList:function(e){var t=this.createNavList();return e.append(t),t},generateNavEl:function(e,t){var r=$("<a></a>");r.attr("href","#"+e),r.text(t);var n=$("<li></li>");return n.append(r),n},generateNavItem:function(e){var t=this.generateAnchor(e),r=$(e),n=r.data("toc-text")||r.text();return this.generateNavEl(t,n)},getTopLevel:function(e){for(var t=1;t<=6;t++){var r=this.findOrFilter(e,"h"+t);if(r.length>1)return t}return 1},getHeadings:function(e,t){var r="h"+t,n=t+1,a="h"+n;return this.findOrFilter(e,r+","+a)},getNavLevel:function(e){return parseInt(e.tagName.charAt(1),10)},populateNav:function(e,t,r){var n,a=e,i=this;r.each(function(r,o){var s=i.generateNavItem(o),u=i.getNavLevel(o);u===t?a=e:n&&a===e&&(a=i.createChildNavList(n)),a.append(s),n=s})},parseOps:function(e){var t;return t=e.jquery?{$nav:e}:e,t.$scope=t.$scope||$(document.body),t}},init:function(e){e=this.helpers.parseOps(e),e.$nav.attr("data-toggle","toc");var t=this.helpers.createChildNavList(e.$nav),r=this.helpers.getTopLevel(e.$scope),n=this.helpers.getHeadings(e.$scope,r);this.helpers.populateNav(t,r,n)}},$(function(){$('nav[data-toggle="toc"]').each(function(e,t){var r=$(t);Toc.init(r)})})}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you provided, $scope is passed in an options object to the init function.
https://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc/#via-javascript

So assuming you have a `<nav id="toc"></nav>` the following should use all headers in the table of contents.

```
Toc.init({
    $nav: $("#toc"), 
    $scope: $("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")
})
```